# How can I get post ID when someone play an Audio?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What I want to accomplish is, to attach **POST ID** to HTML audio control when playing it. I have accomplished the way to get a response when someone clicks on the play button.

Now I'm having issues to attach the post id to that **js** so that I can **COUNT** how many times an HTML audio has been played with correct data.

```
<div id="293">
    <audio class="6" id="mAudio" controls="">
      <source src="horse.mp3">
    </audio>
```

The first piece of code is my audio control rapped up with div**-with POST ID**

```
 window.onload=function(){
    var player = document.getElementById("mAudio");
    player.addEventListener("play", function () {

        console.log("audio playing");
        var post_id = $(this).data('post_id');
        var action = 'play';
        alert('Post id :' + post_id);
        $.ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{post_id:post_id, action:action},
            success:function(data)
            {
               /* alert(data);*/
                fetch_post();
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Then this above code, as I'm trying to get post id, it says **UNDEFINED**

Comment: I have several posts from the database

Comment: `$(this).data('post_id')` where do you define this? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: This was my attempt to get POST_ID, I tried several attempts but I see I'm getting nowhere

Comment: Where do you expect `POST_ID` to come from? What do you expect it be?

Comment: My thinking was, maybe this " $(this).data('post_id')" was gonna give that div ID, because that div ID, is the post id that I'm looking for

Comment: `this.parentElement.id` would give you the player's parent div's ID.

Comment: From the database, when I fetch posts

Comment: so can I attach that with click event or when someone plays the audio of particular post

Comment: How are we supposed to know that?

Comment: I think I'm trying to use the same technique Instagram is using to count the number of views on the insta-videos

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to div who contains id. You need to do this :

```js
var post_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

Comment: `this.parentElement.id` would give you the player's parent div's ID. By pass creating a jQuery object.